# How to add a Java custom library to Robot Framework RIDE

Tags: python, jython, robotframework

I want to create and import a java custom library into RIDE.

Create the Java file based on the below link

(source for creation of test library : http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries)

Here below is the java Library Code:

```
public class MyLibrary{

    public static final String ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL";
    public static final String ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = "1.0";
    public static final String ROBOT_LIBRARY_DOC_FORMAT = "HTML";

    private int counter = 0;

    public void count() {
        counter += 1;
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

    public void clearCounter() {
        counter = 0;
    }    
}
```

Created the JAR file and placed in the path
`D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`

Installed the Jython and set the environment vairables, `JYTHON_HOME=D:\jython2.7.0; JYTHONPATH = D:\jython2.7.0\bin`

Open RIDE and attached the library with the keyword
`Library   MyLibrary`

It displayed the text in red. (Meaning it is not a recognized library).

Comment: The path `D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` seams to be the CPython installation path, not Jython? Why do you put a JAR in it?

Comment: Have you tried running your test from the command line? Maybe it's valid and RIDE just isn't seeing it. In other words, maybe this is a bug in RIDE and can be safely ignored.

Comment: Hi Bryan, Thanks for your reply, Yes, i have tried to run from command line, same issue came.

Comment: Hi Laurent LAPORTE, Thanks for your reply,  I have read some where that we have to place our custom libraries in that path, that's why i have copied to that path

Comment: still an issue?

Comment: yes waman, still issue is there

Comment: How did you run from command line? Can I see the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried compiling the java into class file and placing it under "~\jython2.7rc1\Lib\site-packages\MyLibrary.class"

When I run the below test it worked perfectly for me:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     MyLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
sample
   count
```

Just in case you face issues with path of jython or Jybot, 
place `jybot.bat` in the path `"C:\Python27\Scripts"` folder and change the `jybot.bat` content to absolute value i.e

```
@echo off 
C:\jython2.7.0\bin\jython "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robot\run.py" %*
```

This will resolve the path issues if any!

Comment: When you run from command line you have to run it using jybot

Comment: search for jybot in your pc, I have it under C:\Python27\Scripts\jybot.bat

Comment: Yeah why not.. In fact it just has one line "jython "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robot\run.py" make sure the paths are reachable if not absolute. otherwise copy should work

Comment: we can clear out the comments which would not be useful to others.. I will clear this one too, after you see it.

Comment: Thanks Waman, for your time, Now I am able to run the java custom library

Answer (score 0):

You must add your library to CLASSPATH before running RIDE. For example:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MyLibrary.jar
ride.py
```

Comment: Hi Helio, Thanks for your reply, i have tried this, but no luck, same issue i got